# Resetting chapter counter to 0 for each new part in the book document class

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, etoc

For reasons that may look misguided to some, there are cases where I would like to structure a `documentclass{book}` into `parts` and number the `chapters` of each `part` starting with 1. This works fine as long as there is no need to use `hyperref`. The obvious thing to do is to invoke `\setcounter{chapter}{0}` prior to `\part{...}`. After many attempts to make this work with `hyperref`, first using the `minitoc` package and now using `etoc`, I have come to realize that I have been chasing a pipe dream. `hyperref` interworks perfectly well with either of these packages, but, as in the MWE below, is simply acting on misleading information . In one of his answers `egreg` suggests that `\numberwithin{chapter}{part}` might be a solution to the problem, but I find this is only partially so. I would admit defeat at this stage were it not for the fact that somewhere on the `TeX.SX`, some time ago, I saw an answer which suggested that `chapters` might be referenced not by the `chapter counter` but by a pair `part counter/chapter counter`. A long drawn-out search for that particular answer by trawling through various `tags` and `Users` on the Exchange has proved fruitless. Is it time to abandon all hope?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
% MWE 21June16
% COMMENTS: Resetting chapter counter to 0 for each new part.
%=========================================
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\numberwithin{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}
%===========
\frontmatter
%===========
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % main table of contents, if used
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\shorttableofcontents{Summary Contents}{0}
%\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
.... some text ....

\chapter{Introduction}
.... some text ....
%===========
\mainmatter
%===========
\part{Part ONE}
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Chap. One}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part ONE/Chapter One.
\section{Sec. Alpha}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter One/Section Alpha.
\subsection{Subsec. one}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part ONE/Chapter One/Section Alpha/Subsection one.
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Bravo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter One/Section Bravo.
\subsection{Subsec. three}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. four}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Two}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part ONE/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Charlie}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Two/Section Charlie.
\subsection{Subsec. five}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part ONE/Chapter Two/Section Charlie/Subsection five.
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 3}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 4}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. six}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Delta}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Two/Section Delta.
\subsection{Subsec. seven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. eight}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Three}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part ONE/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Echo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Three/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. nine}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part ONE/Chapter Three/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 5}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 6}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. ten}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Foxtrot}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Three/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. eleven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twelve}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\part{Part TWO}
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Chap. Four}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part TWO/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Golf}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Four/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. thirteen}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part TWO/Chapter Four/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 7}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 8}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. fourteen}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Hotel}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Four/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. fifteen}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. sixteen}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Five}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part TWO/Chapter .
\section{Sec. India}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Five/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. seventeen}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part TWO/Chapter Five/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 9}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 10}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. eighteen}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Juliett}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Five/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. nineteen}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twenty}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Six}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part TWO/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Kilo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Six/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-one}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part TWO/Chapter Six/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 11}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 12}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Lima}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Six/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-three}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-four}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\part{Part THREE}
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents

etc. etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this. What is the question here? A problem with `hyperref`?

Comment: try  with`\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother`

Comment: @touhami: Yes, but after `hyperref` has been loaded, not before!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not a problem with `hyperref`, but I want to  (a) start each `part` with `chapter 1` and (b) have `hyperref` jump to the correct chapters from the respective `tables of contents`.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: Well, it's a problem with `hyperref` then in some sense -- i.e. making correct anchors out of the counter values

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i suppose that it is clear :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting the `chapter` counter on the reset list of `part` is easy with the `LaTeX` core macro `\@addtoreset`

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother
```

Or use the `chngcntr` package and `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}`.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
```

In this case I used `\counterwithin*` to prevent a change of `\thechapter`. For more on this I refer to `chngcntr` documentation. If the part number shall be used as suffixed, the number width in the ToC has to be enlarged!

**Note**

This must be done **after** `hyperref` has been loaded, since `hyperref` has the grip on the counters and anchors already and does perform correct settings then! Doing otherwise will lead to wrong anchors and a plethora of warnings!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
% MWE 21June16
% COMMENTS: Resetting chapter counter to 0 for each new part.
%=========================================
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

% Or
% \usepackage{chngcntr}
% \counterwithin{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}
%===========
\frontmatter
%===========
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % main table of contents, if used
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\shorttableofcontents{Summary Contents}{0}
%\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
.... some text ....

\chapter{Introduction}
.... some text ....
%===========
\mainmatter
%===========
\part{Part ONE}
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Chap. One}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part ONE/Chapter One.
\section{Sec. Alpha}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter One/Section Alpha.
\subsection{Subsec. one}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part ONE/Chapter One/Section Alpha/Subsection one.
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Bravo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter One/Section Bravo.
\subsection{Subsec. three}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. four}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Two}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part ONE/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Charlie}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Two/Section Charlie.
\subsection{Subsec. five}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part ONE/Chapter Two/Section Charlie/Subsection five.
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 3}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 4}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. six}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Delta}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Two/Section Delta.
\subsection{Subsec. seven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. eight}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Three}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part ONE/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Echo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Three/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. nine}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part ONE/Chapter Three/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 5}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 6}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. ten}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Foxtrot}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part ONE/Chapter Three/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. eleven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twelve}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\part{Part TWO}
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Chap. Four}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part TWO/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Golf}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Four/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. thirteen}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part TWO/Chapter Four/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 7}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 8}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. fourteen}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Hotel}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Four/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. fifteen}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. sixteen}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Five}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part TWO/Chapter .
\section{Sec. India}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Five/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. seventeen}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part TWO/Chapter Five/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 9}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 10}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. eighteen}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Juliett}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Five/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. nineteen}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twenty}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Six}
\begingroup
\etocsettocdepth{3}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of Part TWO/Chapter .
\section{Sec. Kilo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Six/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-one}
General comments to all subsubsections of Part TWO/Chapter Six/Section /Subsection .
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 11}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 12}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Lima}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of Part TWO/Chapter Six/Section .
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-three}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twenty-four}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\part{Part THREE}
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents

etc. etc.

\chapter{Foo chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Once again, works like a charm.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: I am in a habit of putting all my macros into  `.sty`files and have just become aware that doing so with `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{}{} \makeatother` may be risky. What is your experience with/view on that?

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: Never ever use `\makeatletter...\makeatother` in a `.sty` or `.cls` file unless you know what you're doing. In this case, `\@addtoreset` is sufficient

Comment: I won't, for the reason you indicated.